# Super types of classes could not be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I can build the project but I can't run it on the phone cause of this bug.

> Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make
>   sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>       class com.app.App, unresolved supertypes: com.base.AppBase

Upon digging dip into Gradle logs, it fails at this task

> :features:wallet:compileReleaseKotlin

A link to the whole project
[here](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template)

I have tried playing around with *implementation* and *api* modes of Gradle dependencies but I've not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try compiling the app with minify on proguard off.See if there is a class being stripped out during compile.

Comment: I tried running debug on phone, the bug comes up. The debug doesn't invoke proguard or minification

Comment: So does it work with emulator but fail on device or you have only attempted with your phone?

Comment: I guess it could not launch on either since it couldn't compile then

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I was referencing [App](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/app/App.kt) in [Wallet ModuleRegistrar.kt](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/features/wallet/src/main/java/com/app/wallet/ModulreRegistrar.kt)

[App](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/app/App.kt) is extending [AppBase](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/base/AppBase.kt) which further extends MultiDexApplication.
Wallet feature did not have dependencies that have [AppBase](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/base/AppBase.kt) and MultiDexApplication classes, so I had to add dependencies for both app base and multidex in the wallet module

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

and

```
implementation project(path: ':base')
```

This way, the wallet module could resolve the supertypes of [App](https://github.com/dev4vin/android-template/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/app/App.kt) class and that fixed the bug.